# How to get explicit unramified covers of an elliptic curve?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Say we begin with an explicit elliptic curve over $\mathbb{C}$, say: $y^2=x(x-1)(x-2)$. According to abstract reasoning this elliptic curve has an (several, in fact) unramified cover with group $C_n$. My question is, how can one find the equations that define this cover? To be very precise: how can one describe the function field extension of $Quot(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2-x(x-1)(x-2)))$ as the quotient field of a polynomial ring modulo an explicit ideal?

It would be nice to have a method that can generate all such unramified $C_n$ covers, but a method that generates some unramified $C_n$ cover would be helpful too.

Answer (score 13):

The covers you seek are exactly the elliptic curves which admit cyclic $n$-isogenies into $E$ (or out of $E$, it doesn't matter).  Proof:  if $X\to E$ is unramified, then $X$ is a genus one curve (by the Riemann-Hurwitz formula).  Choose a base point on $X$ lying above the origin of $E$;  then $X$ is an elliptic curve and $X\to E$ is an isogeny (standard theorem about morphisms between abelian varieties).

The curves $X$ you want are what you get when you quotient $E$ by each of its cyclic subgroups of order $n$.  Finding these $X$ is exactly the purpose of the modular polynomial $\Phi_n(x,y)$.  The way that this works is that if $j(E)$ is the $j$-invariant of $E$, then the roots of $\Phi_n(x,j(E))$ are exactly the quantities $j(E')$, where $E'$ runs over the elliptic curves related to $E$ by cyclic $n$-isogeny.  The modular polynomial $\Phi_n(x,y)$ is difficult to calculate, and its coefficients grow very quickly with $n$;  a Google search comes up with [this reference](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/proceedings-of-the-japan-academy-series-a-mathematical-sciences/volume-71/issue-3/Computation-of-the-modular-equation/10.3792/pjaa.71.48.full) on calculating them.  Once you have the $j$-invariants, it's easy to find the corresponding elliptic curves (this is one nice thing about working over $\mathbf{C}$).

Incidentally, the degree of $\Phi_n(x,j)$, which is (generically) the number of $X$ that you want, is
$$ n\prod_{p\vert n}\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right).$$

Comment: This is the right way to look at these things. But I'm trying to work out a specific case, using Makhalan's example (it has complex multiplication by $i$, after all), which should come up with genuine formulas. It's taking fairly long, though.

Comment: Yes, I should have addressed the CM issue in my answer.  These other curves are going to have CM by $\mathbf{Z}[ni]$.  In fact, the OP is essentially just asking for the minimal polynomial of $j(ni)$, which generates a ray class field of $\mathbf{Q}(i)$.  I don't know a quick way to do this, but maybe it's addressed in Cox' book, "Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$."

Comment: By the way, modular equations in $j$ are a bit of a disaster. The coefficients are much smaller if one works with $\lambda$ instead, or related higher level hauptmoduli. This is discussed in the Borweins' book on $\pi$ and the AGM. Best wishes, Matt

Answer (score 8):

In my perhaps skewed experience, it's much easier, from a computational standpoint, to get isogenies *out of* an elliptic curve than into one. So I'd say that you're really looking into the more uncomfortable end of the telescope.

Again, computationally, once you identify a finite subgroup $S$ of your elliptic curve, it's not too hard to get formulas for the isogeny with $S$ as kernel: use translation (implemented by chord-and-tangent) by the elements of $S$ to define the elements of a Galois group, and find its fixed field inside $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

But the curve you gave is same as $y^2=x^3-x$, and clearly has complex multiplication by $i$: you have $ \lbrack i\rbrack   (\xi,\eta) = (-\xi, i\eta)$. This permits you to write down an example of a cyclic $n$-isogeny any time that $n$ is the sum of two squares in $\mathbb{Z}$, so let's do it for $n=2$. Use the endomorphism $1+i$, which has degree two, so that your curve covers itself in a cyclic $2$-cover. You add $(\xi,\eta)$ to $(-\xi, i\eta)$ on your curve and the result is $(-i/2)(\xi^2-1)/\xi$ for the $x$-coordinate, and $-((1+i)/4)\eta(1+1/\xi^2)$ for the $y$-coordinate. (This point really is on the curve.) The two preceding quantities generate a subfield over which $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ is quadratic, the extension is unramified as desired.

Comment: How do you computationally find the mentioned fixed field? Is this faster than computing Velu's formulas?

Comment: The fixed field is the one generated by the $x$ and the $y$-coordinates mentioned. V\'elu's formulas are probably faster.

Answer (score 6):

Let me expand Felipe's answer a bit.

Vélu's formulae given in the very readable short paper [1]  are very easy to use. For instance if you are given a $n$-torsion point one can immediately write down the Weierstrass equation for the quotient by this point.

To get such a point, one can use the division polynomials which can be computed recursively very fast. The zeroes of this polynomial are exactly the $x$-coordinates of the $n$-torsion points. Oover the complex number it is not difficult to get them also using the parametrisation by the Weierstrass $\wp$-function.

There are quite a few paper improving Vélu's formula. Most importantly, there is Kohel's thesis [2]. Or for instance [3]. These were used in the implementation for isogenies in sage [sage] and in [magma].

[1] MR0294345, Jacques Vélu, Isogénies entre courbes elliptiques. C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris Sér. A-B 273, 1971.

[2] MR2695524, David Kohel, Endomorphism rings of elliptic curves over finite fields. Thesis (Ph.D.), University of California, Berkeley. 1996.

[3] MR2398793, Bostan, A.; Morain, F.; Salvy, B.; Schost, É. Fast algorithms for computing isogenies between elliptic curves. Math. Comp. 77 (2008).

[magma] http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1321

[sage] http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/ell_curve_isogeny.html

Answer (score 5):

Velu's formulas. They are implemented, e.g., in sage.

Answer (score 4):

If you need a quick and dirty example, you can easily get the equation of one of the double covers. If $y^2=x(x-1)(x-\lambda)$ is the equation of your curve, then $$w^2 = (z^2-1)(z^2-\lambda)$$ is the equation of a double cover. In geometric terms, if $E\to\mathbb{P}^1$ is ramified at 0, 1, $\lambda$ and $\infty$, then we get an unramified double cover $E'\to E$ by pulling back over the map $\mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^1 $ given by $x=z^2$. The curve $E'\to \mathbb{P}^1 $ is ramified over the preimages of $1$ and $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that all these covers are given by isogenies of elliptic curves. In order to find those, you should look for a (torsion) subgroup of $E(\mathbb{C})$ isomorphic to $C_n$ (this would give you a system of algebraic equations). Such a subgroup defines an action of $C_N$ on $\mathbb{C}(E)$; the fixed field of this action would give you the function field of the corresponding  elliptic curve.

Comment: Also, the system of equations for $C_n\subset E(\mathbb{C})$ has an abelian Galois group; so it shouldn't be too difficult to solve.

Comment: Sorry for being slow, but I don't really see how this translates to a system of algebraic equations... Can you do a simple example so I can see what you mean?

Comment: I am sorry, but I am too lazy to write down even the simplest example here.:)

First you write the equation $[n]X=0$, where $[n]$ is the multipication by $n$ on $E$. Then you should consider the translates by elements of your chosen $C_n$ and do some explicit Galois theory.